# How to set the order of validation messages?

Tags: xpages

We're using the "Error Messages" XPages (native) control to show the validation errors to user. It works. The validation is done by setting the field as required and entering the field error message. Nothing special.

Now the requirement is to set the error messages in to the same order as they appear in the form. Is this possible?

I guess I could create a custom validator (Java) and doing all the form validations there in certain order (just tested the Validation interface... but not really used id, yet).

Comment: In what order do the error messages appear as default? I assumed that they appear in the same order as they are listed in the source code (but I can see that this might not be the same order as they appear after CSS has been applied)

Comment: I wouldn't expect the order to necessarily be the same as the source. Equally I've not tested it. But I would expect it to run converters before validators, so controls with a converter error may appear first. The other place to check will be the Java class created. That will be what runs, so the order of controls there may be the order in which the controls were created, not the order they appear in the Source pane. In that case, reordering the Java class may change the order of the error messages

Comment: @Paul - actually a field's converter is run just before the value is validated. So its still in the order of where they appear in the tree. So if you have two fields in the component tree, one right after the other, and field 1 fails on validation and field2 fails on conversion, you'll see a validator error, then the converter error.

Comment: If it helps, I have a (live) example here: http://www.btheone.nl/home.nsf/registreren.xsp. Just open the page (in Dutch, sorry) and hit the button "Registreren". You'll see the order is pretty much random. I'd at least expect that similar fields like "Voornaam" (firstname) and "Achternaam" (lastname) would be in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

There's the old (unresolved) argument: should the errors appear next to the control that failed the validation, on top of the form or next to the button you pressed for submission. I tend to put them next to the failed control and have ONE message next to the button reading: "Sorry I couldn't process the input, help me and fix the fields that have error messages next to them". Then sequence isn't an issue any more. If you want to be 100% sure you could instead of the summary control use the individual controls next to each other.

What anyway would be a nice exercise: let the error message control alter the css of the failed control, so it becomes clearer what to look out for.

Comment: You can style the failed control differently using this technique: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2011/07/xpages-styling-invalid-field.html

Comment: I also posted an "enhanced" error messages control that generates links on the error messages so that you can click the error message to set focus to the invalid fields.

http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-control-for-enhanced-validation.html

Comment: The error messages custom control I linked to should now show the error messages in the order that the controls are in the page.

Comment: Thanks Tommy - it should become a part of the extension library!

Answer (score 0):

The Validations are fired one by one in order they are in the component tree.  Depending on how you are wanting them to display you could move the components around and then style them with css.  Or if you are really just wanting to move the order of the summary statements around in the Messages Box, I would just use some JS to move them around I believe they just render as a UL.  Only having one Validator won't really work as the same validator will get fired for every component in the order of the component tree.